# DNN How to create a complex module with multiple controls

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, asp.net-controls, dotnetnuke-imc

My goal are to create a module that holds a listview with entries of xml files. The xml files are just serialized arrays of some object. Country{Code,Name,URL} as an example.

When an entry is clicked another control should show all the items in some kind of item control with styling based on the type(The idea are from WPF). I assume its possible to create some kind of style/rules for possible item types, in above case Country. (any ideas/advises on how to achieve this is welcome).

Now in the list of styled items, one should be able to select wanted items, and export this to a new XML file based on a new type SelectedContries{Code,Name,Url, Params}. The user will then need to add in the extra params in the new list and export(serialize).

My question is now, to do such module what would be the proper way. One module with 3 controls. I am new to module development so please explain deeply. Do i create Asxc files within the module as my controls?

Based on my explained goal above, any links to guides that might be good for exactly this would be nice and any general advises are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of DNN are you running?

Comment: Have you seen the new [RazorHost module](http://www.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2010/12/06/Building-DotNetNuke-Modules-Using-Razor.aspx) stuff? It allows the flexibility of a scripting language for development without limiting deploy-ability. It also holds true to the Razor roots in MVC to allow proper separation of concerns. While this may not directly answer your question (hence it being a comment), it could possibly aide you in your development efforts.

Comment: I have seen it, though i did not think of it as a solution to my problem. I might use a hour looking into if i can solve it using that.  Though i do have a feeling that my problem is a bit bigger then just using the razorhost module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I got you right, that you want to have a grid on your module showing all your country entries read out from a xml file.

The user can edit or add some detail information to those entries and export (serialize) it again into xml.
I would use the implemented Telerik Grid RadGrid (DNN wrapper is called "dnnGrid") to show all xml items in a grid on your module.

Then I would enhance the grid for your special needs adding some new columns or edit the existing (dont know exactly what you want to edit in this grid).
The last step is to serialize the entries again this should be done with a extra button calling the serialize method.

These are rly basic ideas from me. Iam a dnn module developer I think I could help you better if you explain it to me a lil detailed, show me a bit of the xml file and so on.

best regards, noone